# Reinstallation of Barclays Mobile Banking keeps previous installation's data, even after I completely remove app from iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, applications, install

I am trying to uninstall an application (Barclays application) I have installed using Apple Store and reinstall it again.

The problem is that even if I uninstall (by tapping on it and click 'X')it and redownload it from Apple Store, the app still keeps my user data and I don't want that. This happens for the first time, only with this application.

How can I specify in the apple store to forget I have ever installed this app? Can I remove this from my cloud or remove any cookies or cache memory or anything else?

I am using iPhone 6s, iOS 10.2 if that's any help.

Comment: What exactly are you considering to be "user data" in this case?

Comment: @Andreas After I open the app it showed the text I had set in my first installation to help me remember my 5-digit pin. The problem now is solved though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved somehow.

I am not sure if the process I have followed really helped, but this is what I did:

1. Restart iPhone
2. Delete application
3. Reinstall application
4. Go to Settings->iCloud->Storage->Manage Storage->iPhone Latest Backup->Show all apps->Find Barclays record->disable->remove its data
5. Remove application
6. Restart
7. Reinstall and open application

Answer (score 2):

In the Barclays app, go to Settings → Cancel my registration and follow the instructions.

Comment: I have talked on the phone with them and they have told me that they removed my account. So normally, when I open the new installed app, I should not be asked for my 5-digit pin that I have set before. And right now this is what the app asks me. So even if they removed me from the system, the app still thinks that I have an account.